# JS Canvas: Konva bezier issue

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs, konva

I want to draw polyline with round corners like this:

[image]

There is an issue with setting points to line with [Konva library](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Line.html#Line__anchor).

I am trying to use `bezier` property to simulate smooth corners without tension and as doc says:

`if no tension is provided but bezier=true, we draw the line as a bezier using the passed points`

But if I set `bezier: true`, it receives only 3 pairs of points[x,y] and ignores the rest of point array and then just cuts the polyline.

[Example on codeopen](https://codepen.io/mrtester/pen/zYGyxgW)

I don't event have an idea how to draw straight polyline with rounded corners without `bezier` option only with `tension`.

Is there any approach to implement such figure with Konva or other JS Canvas library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make rounded-perpendicular lines with react-konva?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56095148/how-to-make-rounded-perpendicular-lines-with-react-konva) AFAICS this question covers the same ground. My reading of the answer is that it is same concept as @agershun below - line + quad bez + line + quad bez + line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to draw rounded corners only with `Konva.Path`:

```
var path = new Konva.Path({
        x: 20,
        y: 20,
        data: 'm0 0 h 90 q 10 0 10 10 v 80 q 0 10 10 10 h 90',
        stroke: 'red',
      });
```

Using quadratic curve bezier (Q) operator from [svg path rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) we can achieve such result:

[image]

This is an [example](https://codepen.io/mrtester/pen/PoqXPya) on Codepen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the source code of function which allows you to draw pretty nice lines with curved corners. You can create the `Konva.Line` object and add special `sceneFunc` function to the parameters.

```
const BORDER_RADIUS = 40;

let line = new Konva.Line({
    points:[0,0,100,0,100,100,200,100], // put you points array here
    stroke:'#000000',
    strokeWidth:2,
    sceneFunc: function(ctx,shape){
        let points = shape.points();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(points[0],points[1]);
        if (points.length == 4) {
            ctx.lineTo(points[2],points[3]);
        } else {
            let n = 0;

            while (n < points.length-4) {
                let deltaX1 = (points[n+2] - points[n+0]);
                let deltaY1 = (points[n+3] - points[n+1]);
                let br1 = Math.min(BORDER_RADIUS,Math.max(Math.abs(deltaX1/2),Math.abs(deltaY1/2)));

                let deltaX2 = (points[n+2+2] - points[n+0+2]);
                let deltaY2 = (points[n+3+2] - points[n+1+2]);
                let br2 = Math.min(BORDER_RADIUS,Math.max(Math.abs(deltaX2/2),Math.abs(deltaY2/2)));

                let br = Math.min(br1,br2);

                let oneX = points[n+0] + (Math.abs(deltaX1) - br)*Math.sign(deltaX1);
                let oneY = points[n+1] + (Math.abs(deltaY1) - br)*Math.sign(deltaY1);

                ctx.lineTo(oneX, oneY);
                n+=2;
                let twoX = points[n+0] + (br)*Math.sign(deltaX2);
                let twoY = points[n+1] + (br)*Math.sign(deltaY2);

                ctx.quadraticCurveTo(points[n+0], points[n+1],twoX, twoY);
            }
            ctx.lineTo(points[points.length-2],points[points.length-1]);        
        }
        ctx.strokeShape(shape);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me check it in some code sandbox